# Get return code from first command in second command when using pipe

Tags: bash

I want to pipe the output and the return code of a command to another command:

```bsh
somecommand | anothercommand.sh
```

anothercommand.sh can read the output of somecommand but how can this script read the return code of `somecommand`?

`$PIPESTATUS` has no information about preceding commands in anotherstatus.sh (which was expected).

Answer (score 2):

```
{ somecommand; echo "STATUS:${?}"; } | anothercommand.sh
```

will send the status as the last line of the data in the pipe. So it can't be used until all the preceding data has been read. You could send the status only if it was bad, so it would act as a "cancel" operator.

If the order of the data in the pipe is unimportant, you could `tac` the data so the status came first; or buffer it all in memory (maybe in an awk array), or use a file as Stephen suggests, depending on volume.

If `somecommand` only produces data after it succeeds, then a bad status line would come out first (by itself) anyway. In fact, 'success' can often be measured by 'Did I get the data I expected'.

You can also redirect stderr as `2>&1` and look for error messages in the piped data, if they are easy to distinguish from valid data.

Comment: I implemented your solution. Not really beautiful but still not too ugly :) And I don't want to work with temp files.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do this with a pipe, because commands in a pipeline are liable to run in parallel — when `anothercommand.sh` starts, `somecommand` hasn’t finished, and its exit code isn’t known.

If you need this information, you’ll have to split the pipe up and serialise execution:

```
somecommand > tmpfile
anothercommand.sh $? < tmpfile
```

(With appropriate construction for `tmpfile`, *e.g.* using `mktemp`.)